# Local Server access in Browser but not through webview URL in Android

Tags: android, mobile, android-webview

I have an issues while accessing a web page hosted on my local apache server. Its showing 'Webpage not available'. But when I tried the same using emulator browser its working properly.

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8181/www/index.html");
```

Comment: If you are trying on an actual device then it won't work as your local server isn't open to the world. You can use something like ngrok that will make it accessible outside your machine.

Comment: @michaelcarrano.. I am using Emulator and it is not working.. IIn the phone browser it is working using 10.0.2.2 but when I used to load it using webview its not loading..

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the WebView error message?  Also the logcat if there are any interesting error messages from WebView.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, putting `http://localhost:8181/www/index.html` in the browser should work.

You can also use the actual host name or the host IP address.

10.0.2.2 is only valid for the emulator.  The emulator sets up its own network interface and 10.0.2.2 is the address of the emulator's host machine.

On a device, you would have to use the server's host name or network IP address.  I put test code in my app that checks if it's running on emulator vs. device and changes the IP address accordingly.

Comment: I am using Emulator and it is not working.. IIn the phone browser it is working using 10.0.2.2 but when I used to load it using webview its not loading..

Comment: As you are trying to connect via http protocol you need to add below line to your AndroidManifest.xml, I hope it solve your problem:
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not referencing URLs you have no access in your device through internet connection (like fonts, css styles, or JS). This can happend if you use  libraries like bootstrap or google fonts and this may cause trouble.

Also you are trying to access HTTP content and not HTTPS. So you should add to your manifest file this:

```
<manifest>
   ...
   <application 
        ... 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
        ...>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

In my case, the solution was to enable javascript to my webview. Example in java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8181/www/index.html");
        //pass complete url 
}
```

Also in xamarin or Maui this will be, in C#:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_webview);

    _myWebView = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.webview);
    _myWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    _myWebView.LoadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8181/www/index.html");
    _myWebView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClientInOtherPlaceOfMyCode());
}
```